# Blank page when saving edits on post

Tags: posts, errors

Whenever I try to edit a product or a post on WordPress I get a blank page and the edits are not saved. I have been checking Google alot, but there it all seemed to be caused by a plug-in. I only have Woocommerce and WordPress Importer enabled, and I did try to disable those, but the problem wasn't solved.

What could be the cause of this problem? Using WordPress 4.0

EDIT: Also with pages I am having this same issue. I can't save my changes.